# Apply multiple lines of jQuery within a single JS conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some lines of jQuery that I want to apply only if it meets the conditional requirements. Heres the code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    //<![CDATA[ 
    if (location.pathname == "/one-page-checkout.asp") 
       $('#content_area').css("height", "1400px");  <!-- fix footer issue -->
       $('#v65-onepage-ShippingCostDetails tr:nth-child(3)').css("display", "none");
    //]]> 
});
</script>
```

The first line, `"$('#content_area').css("height", "1400px");"`, does what I want, and only applies if the URL has /one-page-checkout.asp. But the second line, `$('#v65-onepage-ShippingCostDetails tr:nth-child(3)').css("display", "none");`, is applying universally throughout my site.

How can I make the second line, and any line after it, obey the conditional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the curly braces on your `if` statement:

```
if (location.pathname == "/one-page-checkout.asp") {
       $('#content_area').css("height", "1400px");  <!-- fix footer issue -->
       $('#v65-onepage-ShippingCostDetails tr:nth-child(3)').css("display", "none");
}
```

Leaving the curly braces off is perfectly valid, but if you do so, only the following line is executed if the statement is true. This can lead to mistakes during maintenance. The indentation is only for readability, it doesn't have any effect on the execution of the code.

Your code, as is, is interpreted like this:

```
if (location.pathname == "/one-page-checkout.asp") 
    $('#content_area').css("height", "1400px");  <!-- fix footer issue -->

$('#v65-onepage-ShippingCostDetails tr:nth-child(3)').css("display", "none");
```

Comment: D'oh. It's always the little things. Thanks for that.